# On $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\eta\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}$, where $\eta$ is a cutoff function, in the spirit of Tao's blog

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

See the second and third paragraphs after the identity labeled as $(10)$ of this [**What's new**: *The Euler-Maclaurin formula ...*, by Terence Tao.](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/)

> **Question.** Let then $\eta(x)$ a *cutoff function*, and $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function. Is it possible calculate the asymptotic behaviour of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\eta\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}$$
>    as the integer $N\to\infty$?
>
> (And if additionally you need to assume that our *cutoff function* satisfies more conditions to get a more precise asymptotic identity feel free to argue such calculations and conditions). **Many thanks.**

Please if such calculation is feasible provide hints or details, as you want. Feel free to add clarifications of your words and details of the theorems that you use.

Comment: $\eta$ is bounded, and $|\mu(n)|\leq 1$, so the series converges absolutely. Therefore, it is $O(1)$ roughly. More precisely, $6/\pi^2 + O(1/N)$ as it was given in the formula without $\mu(n)$ in Prof. Tao's note.

Comment: @i707107 Many thanks, my thoughts were that it was more difficult/different. Any case, you or other user feel free to add the calculations and reasonings as an answer.